# Cannot change background image of div

Tags: javascript

I have no idea why my following code is not changing background image of the image id . When i am hovering over below image elements my background image of div tag(id="image") should change to url of selected image. I have even tried with event.target.src but failed. Though i am able to change text content of the element.What is the problem in the code ?(My image files are working correctly and they are in the project folder)

```js
function upDate(previewPic){
   
    document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage=previewPic.src;
    document.getElementById("image").textContent=event.target.alt;

}
```

```css
/*Name this external file gallery.css*/
body{
    margin: 2%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #b3b3b3;
}
#image{
    line-height:650px;
    width: 575px;
    height: 650px;
    border:5px solid black;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: #8e68ff;
    background-image: url('');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    font-size: 150%;
}
.preview{
    width:10%;
    margin-left:17%;
    border: 10px solid black;
}
img{
    width:95%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src = "gallery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id = "image">
    Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>

<img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "1.jpg" onmouseover = "upDate(this)">

<img class = "preview" alt = "With My Boy" src = "2.JPG" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" >

<img class = "preview" src = "3.jpg" alt = "Young Puppy" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" >

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are neglecting to wrap the contents of the `backgroundImage` property in `url(..)`. Try `document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage="url(" + previewPic.src + ")";` and you will probably find it works.

Comment: Thank you so much :D.. I am inexperienced in JS and had so much trouble with that :)